# How to change Format datepicker header in vuetify

Tags: vuejs2, datepicker, vuetify.js

I want to change "August 2022" to "2022 August" but i can't find anything similar with this  attribute in v-date-picker.
How to change format of this header
[Vuetify Datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tvqV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a propery `header-date-format` that you can use to call your own method of formatting the headers

```
<v-date-picker 
    v-model="picker" 
    :header-date-format="customFormatHeader"
></v-date-picker>
```

```
customFormatHeader(isoDate) {
      const currentDate = new Date(isoDate)
      const month = currentDate.toLocaleString('default', {month: 'long' })
      const year = currentDate.toLocaleString('default', { year: 'numeric' })
      return year + month
}
```